# Laptop hangs when restarting

Tags: 12.10, fstab, reboot

When issuing a reboot from Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 (Linux kernel 3.5), the laptop hangs for about 1m30s on the "Restarting System" line of the shutdown output. This only happens when I have a second drive installed on the laptop (HDD, OS is installed in HDD). When removing the HDD restart progresses normally (no hangs, very fast). Said drive contains both the swap partition (4Gb) and a second ext4 partition, automounted on boot, manually set on `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=0240d6ae-722b-44ed-afad-865b1b3259c4 /                ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime,discard  0  1
UUID=025594dd-cd9f-4a9c-a078-88d69e4677ae none             swap    sw                                            0  0
none                                      /tmp             tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,mode=1777                        0  0
UUID=e9048353-e50c-4d7c-b716-9701bfdb4da9 /media/joao/DATA ext4    defaults                                      0  0
```

Unmounting the drive before reboot doesn't speed up anything, still hangs at the same step.
The strange thing is, **this only happens when issuing a restart, not when shutting down.**

Anyone with any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly either a bug in the ACPI table of your BIOS, in Ubuntu, or a combination of both (possibly in how Ubuntu *handles* the APCI table).  Unfortunately, as stated in the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu is not a place to post bugs.  Therefore, you should report it at [Ubuntu's Launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).